# Flutter SliverList and CustomScrollView Error: 'owner.debugCurrentBuilderTarget == this' : is not true

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, flutter-sliver, sliver-grid

Hello everyone I am trying to build a reusable SliverList into which I just pass the sliver widgets as a List to display, and doubles for padding however currently getting this error

The code of the reusable widget I am trying to build

```
class ScrollScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  ScrollScreen({
    @required this.pageTitle,
    @required this.pageImage,
    @required this.widgets,
    this.color = Colors.white,
  });

  final String pageTitle;
  final String pageImage;
  final List<Widget> widgets;
  final Color color;

  @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return CustomScrollView(physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(), slivers: [
  SliverBar(title: pageTitle, image: pageImage),
  SliverListLayout(widgets: widgets),
]);
```

}

Class of SliverListLayout

```
class SliverListLayout extends StatelessWidget {
final double paddingTB;
final double paddingLR;
final List<Widget> widgets;
SliverListLayout({
@required this.widgets,
this.paddingTB,
this.paddingLR,
});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return SliverList(
  delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
    ...addPadding(widgets, paddingTB, paddingLR), //add padding wraps widgets in a padding widget and returns them,, not the issue works fine elsewhere
  ]),
);
}
```

}
StackTrace:

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building             
NotificationListener<KeepAliveNotification>:
The method '>=' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: >=(0.0)

The relevant error-causing widget was
SliverList
lib\…\custom_widgets\sliverlist_layout.dart:15
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
#1      EdgeInsetsGeometry.isNonNegative
package:flutter/…/painting/edge_insets.dart:52
#2      new RenderPadding
package:flutter/…/rendering/shifted_box.dart:107
#3      Padding.createRenderObject
package:flutter/…/widgets/basic.dart:1652
#4      RenderObjectElement.mount
```

Flutter Doctor:

```
PS C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\AppName> flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5, on Microsoft Windows [VersiÃ³n 10.0.19042.746], locale es-ES)
 
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
[!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.      
[√] VS Code (version 1.52.1)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
PS C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\AppName>
```

addPadding

```
List<Widget> addPadding(List<Widget> widgets,
    [double paddingTB = 25.0, double paddingLR = 25.0]) {
  for (int i = 0; i < widgets.length; i++) {
    widgets[i] = Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
        paddingLR,
        paddingTB,
        paddingLR,
        paddingTB,
      ),
      child: widgets[i],
    );
  }
  return widgets;
}
```

I paste the code from the SliverListLayout class (without the two extra parameters) and everything works fine. Also SliverBar returns a SliverAppBar, and it works fine. Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how to reproduce your problem. I would recommend:

1. Post a complete yet minimal code sample reproducing your problem
2. Post the full console error stack trace
3. Provide more info about your configuration (flutter doctor)

Here is a small code sample doing something simple, similar to (I think) what you try to achieve.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          body: ReusableSliverList(
        title: 'Testing my ReusableSliverList',
        widgetPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32.0, vertical: 16.0),
        widgets: List.generate(10, (index) => Text('Widget $index')).toList(),
      )),
    ),
  );
}

class ReusableSliverList extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final List<Widget> widgets;
  final EdgeInsets widgetPadding;

  const ReusableSliverList({
    Key key,
    this.title,
    this.widgets,
    this.widgetPadding,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      slivers: [
        SliverAppBar(title: Text(title)),
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
            widgets
                .map((widget) => Padding(padding: widgetPadding, child: widget))
                .toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Full **working** code based on your question edit (with addPadding):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ScrollScreen(
          widgets: List.generate(10, (index) => Text('Widget $index')),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class ScrollScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  ScrollScreen({
    // @required this.pageTitle,
    // @required this.pageImage,
    @required this.widgets,
    this.color = Colors.white,
  });

  // final String pageTitle;
  // final String pageImage;
  final List<Widget> widgets;
  final Color color;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(), slivers: [
//      SliverBar(title: pageTitle, image: pageImage),
      SliverListLayout(
        widgets: widgets,
        paddingLR: 16.0,
        paddingTB: 32.0,
      ),
    ]);
  }
}

class SliverListLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  final double paddingTB;
  final double paddingLR;
  final List<Widget> widgets;
  SliverListLayout({
    @required this.widgets,
    this.paddingTB,
    this.paddingLR,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SliverList(
      delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
        ...addPadding(
          widgets,
          paddingTB,
          paddingLR,
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> addPadding(List<Widget> widgets,
      [double paddingTB = 25.0, double paddingLR = 25.0]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < widgets.length; i++) {
      widgets[i] = Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
          paddingLR,
          paddingTB,
          paddingLR,
          paddingTB,
        ),
        child: widgets[i],
      );
    }
    return widgets;
  }
}
```

Comment: that is exactly it however when I moved the code of SliverList to the separate and try to use it the error happens

Comment: Can you provide the full source code of your failing sample?

Comment: what do you need? it is provided above apart from that there is only the addPadding method and the class SliverBar which returns the App Bar

Comment: Well, what I need is the failing part. I suspect it's your `addPadding` method since the error trace mentioned `edgeInsetsGeometry`. But, I'm not sure.

I'll update answer with a full **working** code where I removed the parts you didn't provide: `SliverBar` and `addPadding`.

Comment: thanks, i'll post addPadding and remove it to check just in case

Comment: Nope, the problem is not your `addPadding`. I updated my answer to use your `addPadding`. It would be much easier if you provide a self-contained dart file reproducing your problem.

Comment: Thierry truth is you are too kind. I'll find a work around and truly thank you for all your help

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, your `addPadding` method is overly complicated. Instead of passing `double paddingLR` and `double paddingTB`, you could pass a `EdgeInsets padding` and map your widgets as I did in my first answer. Happy coding! :-)